# Clearcase: How to repair a replica which have oplogs corrupted

Tags: clearcase

I have a replica called KENIA_ICWP_ITEC which, when I try to apply a sync package from the replica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC, a core dump is generated:

```
# multitool syncreplica -import sync_INDRA_ICWP_ITEC_2023-06-02T15.00.04+02.00_28369
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

These the actual oplogs for the replica:

```
# multitool lsepoch replica:KENIA_ICWP_ITEC@/itec/icwp
For VOB replica "/itec/icwp":
Oplog IDs for row "KENIA_ICWP_ITEC" (@ icwpkenia):
 oid:e0f2c369.06e211e6.86f4.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=1795234     (ASTURIAS_ICWP_ITEC)
 oid:9ed5bd47.4d8911e5.8730.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=142972      (DFS_ICWP_ITEC)
 oid:c8f29621.e8a611dd.8b1e.00:1c:c4:93:d2:28=59140877    (INDRA_ICWP_ITEC)
 oid:87730776.630911e7.9303.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=0           (ITECPROD_ITEC_ICWP)
 oid:908bc8fe.f21311e6.920c.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=0           (ITOOLS4_ICWP)
 oid:d35003bc.1cc211e1.9311.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=970073      (JLG_ICWP_ITEC)
 oid:0daafabd.dc9211e5.9fe7.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=14669852    (KENIA_ICWP_ITEC)
 oid:16fba05b.802511e2.8978.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=212378      (OBSOLETE_ASTURIAS_ICWP_ITEC.deleted)
 oid:c9d7f0f2.fc6611e3.8d73.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6=0           (UK_ICWP_ITEC)
```

I have detected that there are some corrupted oplog entries in the database at the replica.

```
# multitool dumpoplog -long -name -invob /itec/icwp -vreplica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC 136082394

 

136082394:

op= uncheckout

replica_oid= c8f29621.e8a611dd.8b1e.00:1c:c4:93:d2:28 (INDRA_ICWP_ITEC)

oplog_id= 59140863

op_time= 2023-06-02T12:07:53Z create_time= 2023-06-02T12:53:52Z

data size= 20 data= 0x8d509c0

------------

ckout_ver_oid= 1a1a16fc.013f11ee.92ea.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6

              (*object not found*)

 

# multitool dumpoplog -long -name -invob /itec/icwp -vreplica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC 136082395

multitool: Error: Operation "xdr_vob_oplog_data_t (decode)" failed: error detected by ClearCase subsystem.

 

# multitool dumpoplog -long -name -invob /itec/icwp -vreplica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC 136082396

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

 

# multitool dumpoplog -long -name -invob /itec/icwp -vreplica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC 136082397

 

136082397:

op= uncheckout

replica_oid= c8f29621.e8a611dd.8b1e.00:1c:c4:93:d2:28 (INDRA_ICWP_ITEC)

oplog_id= 59140866

op_time= 2023-06-02T12:07:55Z create_time= 2023-06-02T12:53:54Z

data size= 20 data= 0x820c9c0

------------

ckout_ver_oid= 1b338011.013f11ee.92f9.98:4b:e1:0c:9c:e6

              (*object not found*)
```

It seems that only the remote oplogs are corrupted, because in the master replica INDRA_ICWP_ITEC, the oplogs are showed correctly.

Is there any way to repair the replica without to be replaced from another healthy replica?

Any help appreciated, Emilio.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the technote "[Operation "`xdr_vob_oplog_data_t (decode)`" failed](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/operation-xdrvoboplogdatat-decode-failed)"

> This error indicates one or more corrupted oplog entries in the database at the replica running the syncreplica command.
>
> ### Diagnosing The Problem
>
> If the oplog is not listed in the error, dumpoplog can be used to attempt to narrow down the problem oplogs.
>
> Determine when the last packet was successfully sent from the problem replica to the remote replica associated with the synchronization that is currently failing:
>
> ```bash
> multitool lshistory replica:<remote replica>
> M:\myview\myvob>cleartool lshistory -minor replica:rep-3
> 04-Nov.13:21   user export sync from replica "rep-1" to replica "rep-3"
>   "Exported synchronization information for replica "rep-3".
>   Row at export was: rep-4=0 rep-3=0 rep-2=0"
> ```
>
> Use the date from the output with `dumpoplog`.
>
> ```
> multitool dumpoplog -long -name  -since 04-Nov.13:21
> ```
>
> If the `oplog` entry order is known, it is possible to start with the entry order value listed in the error minus a few numbers:
>
> ```
>    oplog entry with order:2064989
>    multitool dumpoplog -long -name -from 2064900
> ```
>
> Next run `dumpoplog` in reverse to find the failing oplog in the opposite direction. It will most likely be a different oplog than the one found in the previous step:
>
> ```
> multitool dumpoplog -long -name -reverse
> ```
>
> Both of these commands will most likely fail with a similar error to the syncreplica at or near the oplog producing the problem.

That being said, any resolution should be done in coordination with IBM support.
[Scrubbing the VOB](https://www.philforhumanity.com/ClearCase_Support_28.html) (using the command `/usr/atria/etc/vob_scrubber VOB_PATH`) might help, again, to be done under support supervision. (plus, the process date from 2008, and, depending on your current CC version, might not be relevant today)